# Cant pass pipe's write-end as file desctiptor

Tags: c++, tcl

Pipe's write-end file descriptor is `int` but some functions such [Tcl_MakeFileChannel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/OpenFileChnl.htm#M8) accepts `void*` as file handle. I need to pass pipe write-end to it. How can one convert one type of file handle to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [this reference](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_Tcl_MakeFileChannel.htm) it seems that you simply pass the file descriptor:

```
Tcl_MakeFileChannel(reinterpret_cast<void*>(fd), ...);
```

Also you might want to read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/Gp6yR_ZCA8E).

Comment: That's ugly, but has to be that way to work on Windows, where OS file handles are sized as a pointer type.